# how to store images in database from image tag using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have an image tag like this:

```
  <img src="" id="img1" alt="img1" width="100" height="100" style="display: none;">
```

where the image source is set dynamically by JavaScript. I want to store this image in database using PHP if the source is set. This should happen on click of a button.
This is my PHP code where I'm just checking if database insert works and it does.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $name="checkcheck";
    global $wpdb; 
    $table = $wpdb->prefix ."authorlist"; 
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, 
        array( 
            'authorname' => $name
            )
        );            
    }
```

Now how do I modify this code to store that image?

**EDIT 1:** This is what I did after what you guys suggested

```
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $image = $_POST['img_src_value'];

        global $wpdb; 

        $table = $wpdb->prefix ."authorlist"; 
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'authorname' => $image,
                )
            );            
    }
```

and this is my image tag:

```
  <img src="" id="img1" alt="img1" width="100" height="100" style="display: none;">
  <form method="POST" name="imgForm">
  <input name="img_src_value" type="hidden" class="img_src_value" value="">
  </form>
```

although you must know that this image tag is also within a form itself. So do I put another form tag?

Comment: Please also add code which you have tried, Otherwise your question will go downvoted

Comment: Then remove the form tag. I have update my answer. Please check and in JS have you also added value to hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

Take a form tag and hidden field. With javascript also add img src value to hidden field.

```
<img src="" id="img1" alt="img1" width="100" height="100" style="display: none;">
<input name="img_src_value" type="hidden" class="img_src_value" value="">
```

Then to save

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $imgSrc = $_POST['img_src_value']; /// You can get that value here           
 }
```

Comment: Please update your entire code, to check what you did?

Comment: I've updated my code, please check it out and let me know

Comment: No in JS I only set src value to the img tag. And you should know that I also have other img tags. And using your updated code, I receive a blank entry in the database. @Sudharshan

Comment: You need to add JS to add value to hidden field also

Answer (score 0):

While you set image source dynamically at same time set same value in hidden field and while submitting form you will get it in Request value.

You will receive it as

```
$name="checkcheck";

$image = $_POST['imagesource'];

global $wpdb; 

$table = $wpdb->prefix ."authorlist"; 
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table, 
    array( 
        'authorname' => $name,
        'image' => $image
        )
    );
```